# Cronbach alpha application

Tags: validity, cronbachs-alpha

I developed a questionnaire to measure some factors influence in decision using related literature and after some interviews. Now I have to validate and see how to distribute among the target group. I collected data from 40 students since my target population is 400. So when I run Cronbach alpha in SPSS it turned out to be more than 0.9 with all items. Does this confirm the internal validity of this instrument so I can proceed or do I have to check it further?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/287494/3277 Alpha is not a measure of validity, it is one of measures of item homogeneity

Comment: so how to analyse the pilot data before give it to the main target group