# High Cronbach's alpha

Tags: reliability, cronbachs-alpha, pilot-study

I am conducting a pilot study with a sample size of $n=30$. I am getting a Cronbach's alpha score of $0.933$ to $0.991$. I tried deleting a few items and re-running the analysis. But still, Cronbach's alpha has not changed much. My specific questions are:

1. What could be the reason for this high value?
2. Can I justify this high value and proceed to the main study?

Please share any relevant articles pertaining to this.

Answer (score 3):

> what could be the reason for this high value?

Generally speaking, values of $\alpha$ ranging from 0.93 to 0.99 indicate your scale has a large number of highly related and/or redundant items. More specifically, an $\hat\alpha$ of 0.93 is considered excellent by nearly all standards, though an $\hat\alpha$ of 0.99 may be seen as problematic, as such a high value is an indication of possible item redundancy or even a coding error. Finally, while $\alpha$ is known to perform well in small samples, a sample size of 30 is still small, so it is very possible that sampling variability contributed to your high $\alpha$ estimates.

> Can I justify this high value and proceed to the main study?

You should be good, though the $\hat\alpha$ of 0.99 is worrisome. I would just go back and check for items that have identical responses on certain items.

> Pls share any relevant articles pertaining to this.

Regarding next steps and resources, I would look to conduct an item analysis using classical test theory (CTT). See Bichi (2016) for an accessible introduction, as well as [this CV post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/309460/cronbachs-alpha-optimum-value-is-1-00).

**References**

Bichi, A. A. (2016). Classical Test Theory: an introduction to linear modeling approach to test and item analysis. International Journal for Social Studies, 2(9), 27-33.